# is it possible to use active directory and bcs both in user profile in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, bcs

hi is it possible to use active directory and BCS  both in user profile in sharepoint 2013 for example I want some information like name ,family ,job position ,email and internal number to be filled from active directory and other information like education , Specialized training , university and ... that is that is stored in directory services across the enterprise especially non-Microsoft identity solution (In this example it is a app that has sql server database )to put in a nutshell I want to connect HR system and Education system information in sharepoint 2013 profile and use personal information from active directory

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely doable. On European SharePoint Conference 2015 in Stockholm, Patrick Curran showed us in a demo how this worked. From an architectural viewpoint this is how it works with the new Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM) which is the same as Forefront Identity Manager (FIM) for 2013.

[image]

The presentation is available here: [Expanding User Profiles with Line of Business Data](https://1drv.ms/b/s!ApK-Aenxwmp7hIMnBc4bfs4VeSgfEw)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to first sync User profile Service Application with Active directory and then sync it with BCS. Link below gives step by step method to configure that. BCS part is "Phase 3". [Synchronize user and group profiles in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx)